# I want a new unique online identity - how to find one?

Tags: webapp-rec, username

I want to start a new online identity and use a single common identifier on as many sites as possible.

What web apps or other methods are available for me to check if my proposed nickname is already in use?

I definitely want to avoid any service that might start cybersquatting on the name, if any are suspected of doing that.

Edit: agreed, this does make my online presence very searchable, and I'll give that some more thought.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[namechk.com](http://namechk.com/) will check 149 sites (although some don't seem to work). The check is done on the client-side using JavaScript, so name squatting is not easily possible.

Comment: Nice one, neo.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 9):

Similar to [namechk.com](http://namechk.com) mentioned by @neo, [knowem.com](http://knowem.com) will search 150-300 sites for free, and will register them for you if you pay for their premium service.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great choice too.  I like the way they divide sites into topics.

Answer (score 6):

Long time ago I started to use couple of random letters (Fczbkk) as my nickname. So far it was everywhere I tried to register. Even my domain (http://fczbkk.com) was free. Choosing "Fczbkk" was one of the best decisions I have ever made.

So if you just need an unique identifier for your on-line identity, I'd recommend using any random generator. Or you can smash your forehead against the keyboard or something like that.

Comment: This is an interesting idea.  I was hoping to use something less random but this method is growing on me.  I am going to try bashing my head on the keys shortly :D

Comment: IIRC, this was how xkcd was born too.

Comment: Good idea, and you can choose random letters and then try to give it any meaning. Could result in something quite fun !

Comment: On http://reddit.com it's pretty common to create usernames after CAPTCHAs new users get on registration

Comment: @Benjol Here's the reference http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJOS0sV2a24 @ 44:30

Comment: +1 for "forhead against the keyboard" - as if 20 times per day isn't enough

Answer (score 0):

I made anagrams out of my favourite things until I found one that wasn't taken!

Comment: Zoloft, Fresca, and Xtacy?

Comment: FZeroX. But close!

Answer (score 0):

Also, another option is [namechecklist.com](http://www.namechecklist.com) which will tell you domain availability and search engine rankings as well.

Its not as comprehensive on the social media part, but it is quite elegant.

Answer (score 0):

[getsocialname.com](http://www.getsocialname.com/) will also examine 149 websites (although some don't seem to work). The examine is done on the client-side using JavaScript, so name dead lifting is not quickly possible.

Comment: Are you affiliated with the mentioned service? If yes, please disclose it. Thanks!