# Is there any way to get a squatted username back?

Tags: account-management, username

When trying to find a unique branding for a product, it's hard to find an online username that's free on all desired sites. Even though the .com might be free, someone (real/fake/inactive person, bot, squatter) inevitably has registered that name somewhere.

**Is there any way to petition for an already taken username on any of the popular sites?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're still trying to decide on a name, you could run it through [namechk](http://namechk.com/) as suggested in [this answer.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2722/i-want-a-new-unique-online-identity-how-to-find-one/2725#2725)

You might be able to reclaim the name by contacting the site's administrators, but you'll probably have more luck if you own a registered trademark on it.

Some sites have policies against namesquatting:

- [YouTube](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151655)
- [Twitter](http://help.twitter.com/entries/18370-name-squatting-policy)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a trademark on the name, you could submit it to twitter or facebook and have the username turned over to you.

Answer (score 0):

Although that would work for twitter and facebook there is no way to protect the name from use on other forums.  You could try to reclaim a trademarked name but it would be a lot of work.